# How to pass additional xcodebuild flags through Xcode build settings

Tags: ios, xcode

I am wondering how to pass -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath flag via Xcode build settings. I need it persisted in xcodeproj file so it is available on my CI as well as on my local machine. The idea is to have SPM clone packages in my project folder so that CI is not always downloading them and to avoid redownloading them on my local machine whenever I delete derived data folder. -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath is xcodebuild flag and it is easy to pass it through command line. I was following this article on how to set it up but it does not address my case https://uptech.team/blog/swift-package-manager

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I'm running into the same issues. Azure pipeline does way to long on the packages so I want to cache all SPM. Followed that article as well until the end where they use a different CI. Can't seem to find a good article about SPM and Azure Devops.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to set such a flag on a per project basis, however it's possible to do this globally for your local machine using the Xcode `IDEClonedSourcePackagesDirPathOverride` setting.

### Update Xcode setting

To store the SPM cache in a `~/Developer/spm_cache` directory you should type in a shell:

```bash
$> defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEClonedSourcePackagesDirPathOverride -string "~/Developer/spm_cache"
```

This `spm_cache` directory will basically contain the following files:

[image: SPM cache directory content]

### Warning

Note that it will impact **all** your projects since it's an Xcode general setting. This can be interesting if you share a lot of dependencies between different projects though (eg: for a modularized app where modules have common dependencies)

Before doing so you might want to backup your Xcode preferences:

```
$> defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode > ~/Desktop/XcodeDefaults.plist
```

(you can also access it here: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`)